# What happens on API 8 if I put XML attribute that support higher API 11+

Tags: android

I am aiming to use android:verticalScrollbarPosition to put the scrolling bar on the left.
I know this is supported for Api 11+.  If I compile with target devices being Api 16 but my min supported APi is 8. What would happen to the Api 8 users? Will it crash or will it just ignore this and display scroll bar on right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML attributes introduced in newer versions of Android will simply be ignored on older platform versions. In case your layout look and feel will break because of this you might want to create separate layouts (placing them in separate layout folders) for different platform versions.

Hope this helps.